# Generate JSON file via robot framework process library

Tags: robotframework, mitmproxy

I have a python code thats using mitm proxy to capture website traffic and generate a JSON file and I am trying to integrate that code with Robot using its process library. If I run the python file by itself and initiate Robot tests from different window then the JSON file is generated with no issues but if I run the same file as part of my test setup in Robot(using process library) then no file is generated. Wondering what am I doing wrong here?

Here is my Python code

**tracker.py**

```
from mitmproxy import http, ctx
import json


match_url = ["https://something.com/"]  # Break Point URL portion to be matched


class Tracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flow = http.HTTPFlow

    def requests(self, flow):
        for urls in match_url:
            if urls in flow.request.pretty_url:
                with open('out.json', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as out:
                    json.dump(flow.request.content.decode(), out)

    def done(self):
        print("Bye Bye")
        ctx.master.shutdown()


addons = [
    AGTracker()
]
```

**keyword.robot**

```
Start browser proxy process
    ${result} =  start process  mitmdump -s my_directory/tracker.py -p 9995 > in.txt  shell=True  alias=mitm


Stop browser proxy process
    Terminate process  mitm
```